# How to import all font types inside a variable font file in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fonts, expo

I am a beginner to React Native, and have been fooling around with a project created with expo. I am using the expo-font library with the useFonts hook to import a ttf variable font. The issue I am having is that it only imports one type of font and not all of them. I read through the docs of expo but it says nothing about variable font files.
This is how I'm importing the fonts:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {useFonts} from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useCallback } from 'react';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {

  const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
    "Quicksand" : require('./assets/fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand-VariableFont_wght.ttf')
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded || fontError) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);

  if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: "Quicksand",
    fontSize: 50,
  }
});
```

Is there a way to import all of the font types and weights from the variable fonts file instead of having to import the static fonts one by one?
Thanks in advance!